# Сериализация папки з файлами

Tags: c#, .net, serializable

Как можно выбрать папку с файлами и подкаталогами, а затем сохранить все в один файл `.dat` с помощью бинарной сериализации?

Comment: `Сериализация (в программировании) — процесс перевода какой-либо **структуры данных** в последовательность битов.` Папка с файлами под это определение не походит. Какую цель преследуете?

Comment: Вы хотите получить список файлов и папок в виде строки? Или же вы хотите получить коллекцию каких-то объектов и потому вам нужна бинарная сериализация?

Comment: `winrar a all.rar -m0 folder`

Comment: [ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh485707(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @slippyk, теоретическое задание, в практическом применении данного подхода не уверен

Comment: @Bulson, коллекцию с сохранением структуры, чтобы потом можно было выполнить десериализацию, указать папку и туда "вставить" файлы с подкаталогами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  class Directory
  {
      public Directory[] SubFolders { get; set; }
      public File[] Files { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  class File
  {
      public byte[] Data { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  private IEnumerable<Directory> GetDirectoriesR(string root)
  {
      foreach(var dir in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(root))
      {
          var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
          var directory = new Directory
          {
              Name = dirInfo.Name,
              Files = GetFilesR(dir).ToArray(),
              SubFolders = GetDirectoriesR(dir).ToArray()
          };
          yield return directory;
      }
  }

  private IEnumerable<File> GetFilesR(string dir)
  {
      foreach(var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir))
      {
          var fInfo = new FileInfo(file);

          yield return new File
          {
              Data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file),
              Name = fInfo.Name
          };
      }
  }
```

А потом результат GetDirectoriesR(dir).ToArray() сериализовать BinarySerializer'ом, а потом записать полученные данные в файл...

Comment: Жму вам руку за то, что не поленились написать :)

Comment: Неплохо. Но на гигабайтных файлах код обломается. Кусками надо читать и сериализовать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Это скорее вариант в _какую сторону смотреть_, а уже поделить по Batch'ам, добавить хэширование файлам, добавить сохранение даты и времени создания/правки, NTFS прав, etc... это скорее задача ТС =) Ну или в век больших объемов ОЗУ  и быстрых винтов, можно собраться под x64 и добавить в *.config `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />`, хотя отдельно отмечу, что последнее - это великое зло...

Comment: + но вариант с архивом мне больше по душе

Comment: @kimaman2, спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: @СергійПотоцький Тогда можно отметить пост как ответ =)